# removing HTML from Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am returning some text from a server with HTML around the text I need.  Using javascript/jquery, what would be the best way to remove all of the html markup so all that i log or save is just the text: "This is the body and text of the meeting."

Thanks - below is what the html looks like.  I keep getting stuck with returning the

> ```
> > <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
> > charset=utf-8"><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Exchange
> > Server"><!-- converted from rtf --><style><!-- .EmailQuote {
> > margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; }
> > --></style></head><body><font face="Calibri" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">             <div>This is the body and text of the
> > meeting.</div><div>&nbsp;</div></span></font></body></html>
> ```

Comment: try with `var str=$('body').text();`

Comment: If I use that example with the above HTML, I return this:   Heading!<!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } -->This is the body and text of the meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
var yourtext = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;'+
'> charset=utf-8"><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Exchange'+
'> Server"><!-- converted from rtf --><style><!-- .EmailQuote {'+
'> margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; }'+
'> --></style></head><body><font face="Calibri" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">      '+                   '<div>This is the body and text of the'+
'> meeting.</div><div>&nbsp;</div></span></font></body></html>';

var textWithoutHtml = $(yourtext).children().text();
```

Comment: That worked!  this one actually removed all of the HTML

Answer (score 4):

using regex you can remove html tags from yourtext.

javascript:

```
    $('textarea').on('input', function (){
    $('div').text(sanitize(this.value));
});

var protos = document.body.constructor === window.HTMLBodyElement;
validHTMLTags  =/^(?:a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|article|aside|audio|b|base|basefont|bdi|bdo|bgsound|big|blink|blockquote|body|br|button|canvas|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|data|datalist|dd|del|details|dfn|dir|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|figcaption|figure|font|footer|form|frame|frameset|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|head|header|hgroup|hr|html|i|iframe|img|input|ins|isindex|kbd|keygen|label|legend|li|link|listing|main|map|mark|marquee|menu|menuitem|meta|meter|nav|nobr|noframes|noscript|object|ol|optgroup|option|output|p|param|plaintext|pre|progress|q|rp|rt|ruby|s|samp|script|section|select|small|source|spacer|span|strike|strong|style|sub|summary|sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|time|title|tr|track|tt|u|ul|var|video|wbr|xmp)$/i;

function sanitize(txt) {
var // This regex normalises anything between quotes
    normaliseQuotes = /=(["'])(?=[^\1]*[<>])[^\1]*\1/g,
    normaliseFn = function ($0, q, sym) { 
        return $0.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); 
    },
    replaceInvalid = function ($0, tag, off, txt) {
        var 
            // Is it a valid tag?
            invalidTag = protos && 
                document.createElement(tag) instanceof HTMLUnknownElement
             || !validHTMLTags.test(tag),
            isComplete = txt.slice(off+1).search(/^[^<]+>/) > -1;

        return invalidTag || !isComplete ? '&lt;' + tag : $0;
    };

txt = txt.replace(normaliseQuotes, normaliseFn)
         .replace(/<(\w+)/g, replaceInvalid);

var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
tmp.innerHTML = txt;

return "textContent" in tmp ? tmp.textContent : tmp.innerHTML;
}
```

HTML:

```
Enter some HTML here, invalid tags aren't removed:<br>
```

Output:

Answer (score 3):

JS:

```
string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Jquery (possibly slower):

```
string.text();
```

Comment: When using this i still return the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/8JSZX/143/

Comment: @user2816352 You are not calling the function see this http://jsfiddle.net/8JSZX/147/

Comment: Use the JS version like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8JSZX/148/

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$(yourtext).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your server response using AJAX or whatever you are using.
2. Store Server Response inside  tag.
3. Get Outer text of that div using javascript or .text() using jQuery.

Please see working example http//jsfiddle.net/imdadhusen/Hs4Q6/7/